# Why Regularization can't accept Φ as penalizing parameter?

Tags: machine-learning

Why Regularization can't accept Φ as penalizing parameter? but accept Φ^2 (L2) AND |Φ| (L1).

are there Any other penalizing parameter forms?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1):

The Regularization term is usually a vector norm because it outputs an scalar value that means the length of the vector in a certain space. What it's important here is that it's a scalar value, not a vector. You cannot use a single vector as regularisation term, because the regularization value is added to the loss function, which is also a scalar. Thus, you need to compute some scalar from this vector and use it, and that's exactly what a vector norm does. As you can image, having a scalar value as regularisation term is pretty intuitive: the higher, the more regularization.

And yes, there are some other regularization methods. For instance, the elastic net method, which combines L1 and L2 norm functions. But usually, the most popular ones are single L1 (Lasso regression) and single L2 (ridge regression). I encourage you also to look for the Bayesian assumptions that are behind the regularization terms, they are pretty interesting and a completely different point of view ;)
In other family of algorithms such as Neural Networks, the regularization is done by early stopping, or in Variational Autoencoders with the prior belief of a isotropic Gaussian in the latent variables distribution.

Comment: Thank you. even though some people vote it closed. But. thanks for your explanation.